# Bitbucket - git push fails. Packet corrupt | Broken pipe

Tags: git, push, ubuntu-14.04, bitbucket, corrupt

A strange problem suddenly occurred in most of my repos. I used to push normaly via SSH to Bitbucket, different types of files (.html, .pdf, .png, .js, .css, etc.) without any problems.

Few days ago I started getting the following error when trying to push:

> Received disconnect from 104.192.143.3: 2: Packet corrupt
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

It seems to happen when images or pdf files are included in my commits. For minor changes in text files, I can push without any problem.

I tried to push via HTTPS and got the following error:

> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Tried to increase  the httpPostBuffer:

> (git config http.postBuffer 524288000)

but with no success. Tried to create .gitattributes file for proper handling of files and then removed cached index, again with no success.

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Git version is 1.9.1.

Tried to reproduce the error on a Windows machine, by cloning the repo and making similar changes, but  I wasn't able, as it pushed normally.

I am stuck.

Any help aprreciated.

Thanks in advance,
George Georgopoulos

Comment: This is more of a question for Bitbucket support so we can actually look at your repo and see what's up. Can you email us all the relevant repo details at support@bitbucket.org?

Comment: I've got the same today on a Windows maching.
Received disconnect from 104.192.143.1: 2: Packet corrupt

fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument

Comment: I have same problem on Ubuntu 15.04. I contacted the support 2 weeks ago but they still cannot locate source of problem.

Comment: I have contacted BitBucket support and we are still trying to figure out where is the problem. Seems like it is on my network as I tried to push from another computer (with Windows 10 installed) and sometimes it also failed. But when I tried from my cloud-based dev server (Linode) I was always able to push successfully. I'll return as soon as I have something new. Thanks!

Comment: That is not correct, pushing work on heroku, github and others, it's mainly bitbucket issue that wasn't present before. I'm runing ubuntu 14.04 - git 1.9.1

Comment: @GeGe Did you ever get a reply from BitBucket? I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: @BenBearFish, I had several conversations with BitBucket support but none of these solved my problem. I never figured out if it was the network. Few days after the problem occurred I switched company, so I don't know if it finally was solved. :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case I switch my connection from ADSL to the hotspot of my SmartPhone and it works...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to install a rate limiter on your computer.

I installed Network Link Conditioner from apple, set it to 500kbit/s upload speed maximum and I can push to bitbucket again.

Get Network Link Conditioner from apples developer site.  It's part of the Hardware IO Tools for Xcode package.   It was a little fiddly to get running. I had to install the version that matched my Xcode installation before it worked, and rebooted at least once.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Connected using a VPN and fixed the issue.
Really sad that some ISPs and/or sysadmin are blocking access to bitbuket.

Comment: Yes. Was working at a cafe. They simply block bitbucket apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well (on three different repos on two different pcs). I know it didn't work for you, but switching to `https` allowed us to push the commit that was causing issues, then switched back to `ssh` and had no issues since.

There doesn't seem to be a reason for these specific commits to be causing these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I connected using [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue and contacted the support. They asked me to if I was behind any firewall or a proxy which I wasn't.

But I just thought to change my ISP and try again and voila, it worked. Just in case it helps anybody else.

Comment: One doesn't simply change his ISP

Comment: Do you mean change you IP address?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on an Ubuntu 14.04 VMware virtual machine running on Windows 10.
Git version was the same as yours (1.9.1), which brought me to your question.
I tried many different things (including recompiling git with openssl), but nothing worked.

At some point **I changed the network settings on the VM** (selected **bridged** instead of NAT network interface) and it worked.

It turned out the solution to my problem was unrelated to the specific system. Hopefully this answer will save other people some trouble.